# Left Join table error missing aliases

Tags: mysql, left-join, aliases

I wrote a query in mysql to get all records from job_input table and corresponding output records if avaible from job_output table. It gives the following error:

> Query: select ji.* from `job_input` as ji left join (select
>   SUM(jo.O_Total) AS Total_Output, SUM(jo.O_XS) AS XS_Output,
>   SUM(jo.O_S) AS ...
>
> Error Code: 1248 Every derived table must have its own alias

Below is my query. What am I doing wrong??

```
SELECT ji.* 
    FROM `job_input` AS ji LEFT JOIN
    (SELECT 
    SUM(jo.O_Total) AS Total_Output,
    SUM(jo.O_XS) AS XS_Output,
    SUM(jo.O_S) AS S_Output,
    SUM(jo.O_M) AS M_Output,
    SUM(jo.O_L) AS L_Output,
    SUM(jo.O_XL) AS XL_Output,
    SUM(jo.O_XXL) AS XS_Output,
    SUM(jo.O_Other) AS Other_Output FROM `job_output` AS jo GROUP BY jo.`Job_InputID`)
    ON jo.`Job_InputID`= ji.`Job_InputID`
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to put alias to join table?

```
SELECT ji.* 
    FROM `job_input` AS ji LEFT JOIN
    (SELECT 
    jo.`Job_InputID` AS JobID
    SUM(jo.O_Total) AS Total_Output,
    SUM(jo.O_XS) AS XS_Output,
    SUM(jo.O_S) AS S_Output,
    SUM(jo.O_M) AS M_Output,
    SUM(jo.O_L) AS L_Output,
    SUM(jo.O_XL) AS XL_Output,
    SUM(jo.O_XXL) AS XS_Output,
    SUM(jo.O_Other) AS Other_Output FROM `job_output` AS jo GROUP BY jo.`Job_InputID`) AS table2
    ON table2.JobID = ji.`Job_InputID`
```

Comment: This fixed the error but doesn't show results from job_output table. Only all records from job_input table is showing.

Comment: @azj You only select from ji